# Append description on top of log. I am using log4j

Tags: log4j

I need to append a small log description at the top of the log like shown below.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to extend the `PatternLayout`. Take a look [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/535099/oa/Inserting-Header-Text-Log-file)